# Permalink Rewrite to include Custom Taxonomy Term

Tags: custom-taxonomy, permalinks, terms

I've created a custom taxonomy for posts using

```
register_taxonomy( 
    'discipline', 
    array('post'), /* if you change the name of register_post_type( 'custom_type', then you have to change this */
    array(
        'hierarchical' => true,     /* if this is true it acts like categories */             
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __( 'Disciplines' ), /* name of the custom taxonomy */
            'singular_name' => __( 'Discipline' ), /* single taxonomy name */
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Disciplines' ), /* search title for taxomony */
            'all_items' => __( 'All Disciplines' ), /* all title for taxonomies */
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Discipline' ), /* parent title for taxonomy */
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Discipline:' ), /* parent taxonomy title */
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Discipline' ), /* edit custom taxonomy title */
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Discipline' ), /* update title for taxonomy */
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Discipline' ), /* add new title for taxonomy */
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Discipline Name' ) /* name title for taxonomy */
        ),
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'discipline',
            'with_front' => false
        ),
        'show_ui' => true,
        'query_var' => true,
    )
);
```

If I use just %postname% in the permalinks page, I get URLs like:

whatever.com/discipline/name-of-post

I want to get the URL to read

whatever.com/parent-term-name/name-of-post

I've removed the discipline part using the "Remove Taxonomy Base Slug" plugin but can't figure out how to get the term name included AND have permalinks to other parts of the site unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to include the discipline variable in the custom permalink structure

```
/%discipline%/%postname%
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't get replaced with the actual term name. My urls just contain the phrase 'discipline'!

Comment: Did you flush the permalinks after registering the taxonomy? Go to Settings>Permalinks and click save.